# Quick Sort implementation in Java, Pivot Selection

Tags: java, quicksort

I have implemented a generic quickSort on an ArrayList in java, however it only works if I select the pivot as the right most item int the array. I have tried selecting the middle item and a random item, both of these return the ArrayList only partially sorted. I am specifically wondering why the two commented out pivot selection methods in quickSortRecursive cause the ArrayList to not be all the way sorted. Any help is appreciated!

```
public static <T> void quicksort(ArrayList<T> a, Comparator<? super T> cmp){
    int left = 0;
    int right = a.size()-1;
    quickSortRecursive(left, right,a, cmp);
}

private static <T> void quickSortRecursive(int left,int right, ArrayList<T> a,  Comparator<? super T> cmp){

    if(left >= right){
        return;
    }
    T pivot = a.get(right);
    //T pivot = a.get(rand.nextInt(a.size()-1));
    //T pivot = a.get((left+right)/2);

    int partition = partition(left, right, pivot, a, cmp);
    quickSortRecursive(0, partition-1,a,cmp);
    quickSortRecursive(partition+1, right,a,cmp);

}


private static <T> int partition(int left,int right,T pivot, ArrayList <T> a,Comparator<? super T> cmp){

    int leftCursor = left-1;
    int rightCursor = right;

    while(leftCursor < rightCursor){
        while(cmp.compare(a.get(++leftCursor), pivot)<0);
        while(rightCursor > 0 && (cmp.compare(a.get(--rightCursor), pivot)>0));
        if(leftCursor >= rightCursor){
            break;
        }
        else{
            swap(leftCursor, rightCursor, a);
        }
    }
    swap(leftCursor, right, a);
    return leftCursor;
}


public static <T> void swap(int left,int right, ArrayList<T> a){
    T temp = a.get(left);
    a.set(left, a.get(right));
    a.set(right, temp);
}
```

Comment: Why not to swap the selected element with the rightmost? The randomness properties does not depend on the array final position of the elements. Very good algorithms books proceed in this way.

Comment: You should talk a little bit about what you have done to diagnose the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

So you're almost getting there but there are a few things I can see wrong with this code:

- `<T>` is usually used to declare a function with an unknown Type or to create Generic functions, it's not necessary to use that here. Instead of an arrayList you can simply use an array of any type of your choice i.e. `int[] data`.
- Pivot is an index that is arbitrarily chosen within the range of the data although it's common to use `(left + right) / 2` it's type is most likely an `int`.
- You have two methods `quickSortRecursive` and `partition`. However these belong in one function together as you need to calculate your pivot for each subset of the data to be sorted. This method need not have a return type so simply use `void` in your method declaration.

Once you have successfully divided the data into a subset, you need to pick a pivot, swap that pivot with the last item in that subset.

Then you need to loop through the data subset and compare each data item with the pivot value (which is located at the end of the data subset as we just swapped it). If the data item is less than the value at the pivot index, then 
swap the items.

After all the items have  been swapped it is necessary to put the data at the pivot index back in it's place by swapping it with the last item to be sorted.

*Only then* can you recursively call the function on the rest of the data:

When you recursively call the function:

```
quickSortRecursive(0, partition-1,a,cmp);
quickSortRecursive(partition+1, right,a,cmp);
```

You should be passing left not 0 into the function, as passing 0 will result in always sorting from the far left side of the data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`--rightCursor` first decrements the variable then use it (already decremented).

So since `right=a.size()-1;` the rightmost element will be neglected (except for  the pivot one which is compared anyway).